# C++ Qt - Sending POST request only after reply for the last one is finished

Tags: c++, qt, post

I have a desktop application that sends JSON strings (some device information) to a web service using POST requests, and the web service replies with a small JSON string as an indicator if the request was successful or an error occurred while storing information in the database.

This data is sent when the user clicks a button and executes the following:

```
foreach(QString device, deviceList)
{
    QByteArray jsonString = device.toUtf8();
    currentRecord = device;

    // POST data size for "Content-Length" header
    QByteArray postDataSize = QByteArray::number(jsonString.size());

    // Build POST request
    QUrl serviceURL("http://www.mywebsite.com/awesomeWebService");
    QNetworkRequest request(serviceURL);
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Length", postDataSize);

    // Send POST request
    networkManager->post(request, jsonString);
}
```

When each POST request is sent I handle the finished() signal of the reply in a slot called replyFinished(). I know that the QNetworkAccessManager (networkManger in my case) is sending requests asynchronously, so I think that theoretically I could receive a reply for the first device in the list later than the reply for the second device.

If all information is successfully sent it doesn't matter in which order I handle the replies in the replyFinished() method, but in case an error occurs on the server side, I want to be able to know for which device string the web service gave me an error. This could be accomplished if the web service returned me the device string with the error indicator, but this is not implemented and I have to figure out a way to do it on my side if it is possible. This is why I put currentRecord = device; in the foreach loop, in an attempt to track the device string (and use it in the replyFinished() method, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way I can force the next POST request to be sent only after I receive the reply for the last request?

I tried to use something like this (the while loop would break when the reply is finished), but the application froze:

```
QNetworkReply *reply;
while(!reply->isFinished())
{
    reply = networkManager->post(request, jsonString);
}
```

Comment: You should really take a look at Qt Signals/Slots mechanism, it's such a wonderful feature :). You don't have to make while loops that block the main application. You can make all through Signals and Slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitting in a while loop prevents Qt from processing incoming events, which is why your application freezes.  Instead you should make one request, wait for the `finished()` signal, then make the next request in the queue from your `replyFinished()` slot.  Repeat until all requests have finished.

Comment: I know I have to do it, but the question is how to wait for the finished() signal inside the foreach loop?

Comment: Don't.  It is possible using `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` but I would really recommend that you restructure your code so that you don't need to.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do it with events (signals/slots), and avoid loops.